# An efficient way of finding the closest point of a sampled function to another point

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a function $f(x)$, has been sampled into a sequence
$$
y_0, y_1, ..., y_{n - 1}
$$
at points $x_k = k \Delta x$. $f(x)$ is neither smooth or monotone.

Under this assumption, what is the fastest way of finding
$$
\min_{k=0}^{n - 1}|P - (x_k, y_k)|
$$
where $P$ is an arbitrary point?

I could do a linear search, but I need to compute the minimum distance for $n^2$ different points which makes the overall algorithm $n^3$.

Comment: Is there any relation between the $n^2$ points or are they "random" ?

Comment: @user16034 In fact, they are coordinates in an image, and f(x) goes across the image (from left to right).

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) for your points, and then use a [point location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location) algorithm. Because you need quadratic work regardless you don't even need an efficient algorithm for the Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If You sample the function once beforehand, the problem breaks down to a simple [Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). There are many different data structures and algorithms for solving the nearest neighbor problem.

As long as $x_k$ and $y_k$ are fairly low-dimensional, one popular solution is the [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) which can be build in $\mathcal{O}(n \log{n})$ for your $n$ sample points. Querying the closest sample points to the $n²$ search points usually takes $\mathcal{O}(n^2\log{n})$.

Kd-tree libraries are available in most programming languages, e.g. for NumPy, there is [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). Kd-trees are a fast general purpose solution but likely not the fastest specific solution.

Comment: Interestingly a kd-tree could reduce the number of iterations spent on finding the minimum, but not sufficiently to compensate for the higher overhead at each iteration, making it slower.

Comment: Without knowing the data and the implementation its hard to say. Maybe $n$ is too small for kd-tree to be useful? Are You fitting the function to the points? In that case You could build a kd-tree of the points instead of for the function values.

Comment: Here, n is in the range 1024 to 4096.

Comment: That feels relatively small for kd-trees to me. Building the tree may be more expensive than the savings in query time.

Comment: Actually building the tree is quick enough. However, individual lookups take way longer than they should.

Comment: If You are using [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), You can bundle all nearest-neighbor queries into one vectorized query. I have not done that in a while, but the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query) should give You a hint of how to do it.

Comment: That could be one of the problems. Is it really possible to vectorize such query using simd? Another problem is irregular memory accesses. A third problem is bad branch prediction. A forth problem is that it is harder for the compiler to optimize a kd-tree query than a straight loop over all values.

Comment: Python/Numpy somewhat misuses the term vectorization as "function allows vectors/arrays of inputs". So it does not necessarily mean SIMD. But You can absolutely use SIMD to speed up spatial data structures, e.g there is a very interesting [GDC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BIfqfC1i7U) about SIMD in Titanfall 2's physics engine. But before You build Your own SIMD implementation of a KD-Tree, I would try alternatives like [Ball Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree) or different KDTree construction strategies.